# Django Rest shows TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn django rest on a existing blog project. My project has a model named "BlogPost". There I have created an endpoint to GET the blogpost object. I can create a blog successfully from django admin, but whenever I give the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/postings/1/", it shows the error `"TemplateDoesNotExist at /api/postings/1/"`, while there isn't any error in my terminal. it shows `"GET /api/postings/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 85630`. Can anyone help me where am I doing wrong?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    # pk aka id --> numbers
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    content     = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from postapp.models import BlogPost
from .serializers import BlogPostSerializer

class BlogPostRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.all()
```

Here is the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers   
from postapp.models import BlogPost

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'user',
            'title',
            'content',
            'timestamp',
        ]
```

My urls.py inside the api

```
from .views import BlogPostRudView

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', BlogPostRudView.as_view(), name='post-rud')

]
```

and my urls.py inside the project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = "testproject"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/postings/',include('postapp.api.urls')),

]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to add `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project's `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    ................
```

You may also need to run `migrations` after adding it.

Everything about your code seems alright

Answer (score 1):

Django rest framework will provide a template by default. i wonder if something is not done right when setting up the application? Possibly template paths? Have you tried hitting the endpoint with a REST client or curl? Something like:

`curl -X "GET" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/postings/1" -H "Accept: application/json"`

I would expect the above to work. In that case have a look at your template paths (although the HTML template is not required for a REST API.

Comment: *Django rest framework should provide a template by default* -- this is incorrect.

Comment: @heemayl it's not incorrect. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/

Comment: Thats when you're passing HTML as response,. What if I only deal with JSON?

Comment: Browesable API will be rendered if accept header is not set to JSON, or you visit the endpoint URL through a Web browser.

Comment: My question was rhetorical. Whether I need a template or not totally depends on the use case.